# associative array is not finding the specified index

Tags: php

I am having some problem with associative array. When I check the array `$keywordstoupdate` does return a value  but when it reaches to `echo` it say `Keyword` is undefined. However, `print_r()` prints it and everything is fine from that perspective. but when I try to echo then the `Keyword` is missing.

```
function getkeywords($mysqli, $someid)
{

    $keywords=array();
    $query='select Keyword from keywords where someId=?';
    $stmt= $mysqli->stmt_init();
    $stmt->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $someid);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($Keyword);
    while($stmt->fetch())
    {

        $keywords[]= array("Keyword" => $Keyword);
    }

    return $keywords;
}

  $keywordstoupdate[]=getkeywords($mysqli, $someid);

  <textarea id='textarea_keywords' name='keywords'>
  <?php
  if(count($keywordstoupdate)>0){
    for($i=0; count($keywordstoupdate)>$i; $i++){ 
     echo ( $keywordstoupdate[$i]['Keyword']." ");
    }
  } ?></textarea>
```

The result of `print_r()`

```
      Array
   (
         [0] => Array
         (
               [Keyword] => asdf
         )

    )
```

Comment: What variable is that `print_r()` displaying?

Comment: did you printed $keywordstoupdate?

Comment: Yes... That is the result of `$keywordstoupdate`.. and by the way I think I have been answered..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're creating a three-dimensional array accidentally, while your loop is expecting a two-dimensional array.

Try changing:
`$keywordstoupdate[]=getkeywords($mysqli, $someid);`

To:
`$keywordstoupdate=getkeywords($mysqli, $someid);`